# js get html datatable pointer from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables, django-templates

i am working on django table where my main page is showing a table using databaleview.

i am tring to make a js function in my html which will draw the table again once it is over.

the relevant parts in my main html:

```
<div class="row">

        {{ datatable }}
        <button name="me" id="changeread" type="button">Read / Unread</button>

    </div>


<script>
   $( function() {
        var xeditable_options = {};
        var table = datatableview.initialize($('.datatable'),
                {

                    lengthMenu : [ [10, 20, 50, 100, -1 ], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All" ] ],
                    fnRowCallback:
                            datatableview.make_xeditable(xeditable_options),

                    bProcessing : true

                }
        );
```

this is the function i want to redraw the table once it is over:

```
 function myIpfunc(d){
        if( !confirm( "Are you sure you want to do this to -> " + d + " <- ?" ) ){
                return;
            }
        var table = $(this).DataTables_Table_0_wrapper;
        #var table = $(this).datatable #didnt work also
        table.draw()
```

in inspect element option of the page it is under:

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
```

any idea how i should to the "var table = ?"

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `table` variable global so that it can be re-used within other functions:

```
<script>
   var table;
   $( function() {
        var xeditable_options = {};
        table = datatableview.initialize($('.datatable'),
        ...
```

then your function just becomes:

```
function myIpfunc(d) {
    if( !confirm( "Are you sure you want to do this to -> " + d + " <- ?" ) ){
            return;
        }
    table.draw();
}
```